# Serverless Deploy crashing for ruby app using serverless-ruby-package on mac

Tags: ruby, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using serverless for building aws app on a mac. When I do not use the "serverless-ruby-package" and deploy, I get

```
"errorMessage": "cannot load such file -- curb",
```

as the gems are not properly compiled.

The moment I add

```
plugins:
  - serverless-ruby-package
```

and execute

```
sls deploy
```

or

```
sls package
```

I get

```
Type Error ----------------------------------------------

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
      at PackageRubyBundlePlugin.beforePackage (/Users/xxxxxx/node_modules/serverless-ruby-package/index.js:85:45)
      at PluginManager.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:576:20)
      at async PluginManager.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:634:7)
      at async Serverless.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:327:5)
      at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/scripts/serverless.js:704:9
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a bug with the `serverless-ruby-package` plugin, as it's been reported by other [users](https://github.com/joshuaflanagan/serverless-ruby-package/issues/34)

You may consider adding a comment here.

Comment: Well, that question is by one of my team members. I was hoping to get some other help here.

Comment: My best guess is that the `serverless-ruby-package` is relying on framework internals that have been changed in newer versions of the serverless framework. The other option is to revert back to an earlier version that worked.